# Mutation events in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, dom-events, mutation-events

I'm trying to listen for changes in a XML structure using Javascript. I've got the following code:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "root", null);
doc.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
                       alert("changed!");
                     }, false);
doc.documentElement.appendChild(doc.createElement("test"));
```

This is not working. However the following code *does* work:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
                           alert("changed!");
                          }, false);
document.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("button"));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your examples work in recent Firefox and Opera but only the second works in WebKit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari). This looks like an oversight or bug in WebKit, although I can't find an issue in their issue tracker about it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just found this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26147

This really is a bug in Webkit.